# Angular 15+ error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular

I have this error when loading my project in angular, but it only occurs in components that are called from other components in window mode (for example, one of them is called when an icon is clicked).

This error is supposed to occur because I'm not importing the corresponding module, but the fact is that I am. What is this error due to?

[image]

archivo TS

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, ViewChild,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { AuthServiceService } from 'src/app/services/auth-service.service';
import { ParametersGlobalService } from 'src/app/services/dataGlobal/parameters-global.service';
import { ValidacionesService } from 'src/app/services/dataGlobal/validaciones.service';
import { EndPointSeguimientosService } from 'src/app/services/endpoint/end-point-seguimientos.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-comentarios-seguimiento',
  templateUrl: './comentarios-seguimiento.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comentarios-seguimiento.component.css']
})

export class ComentariosSeguimientoComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public datos:any,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public endPointSeguimientos:EndPointSeguimientosService,
    public authService : AuthServiceService,
    public validaciones: ValidacionesService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    public varGlobales: ParametersGlobalService
  ){ 

  }

  formComentarios = new FormGroup({
    nombreComentarios: new FormControl(),
    nuevoComentarios: new FormControl()
  });
  }
```

HTML

```
            <form [formGroup] = "formComentarios"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for=""><b>Cliente:</b></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nombreComentarios" readonly formControlName="nombreComentarios" style="font-size: 12px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nuevoComentarios" formControlName="nuevoComentarios" rows="3" [placeholder]="placeholder">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="offset-end" style="text-align: right;">
                    <button class="btn btn-square btn-blue">
                        <div class="flex">
                            <span class="material-icons">
                                save
                            </span>
                            Agregar Comentario
                        </div>
                   </button>
                   <span class="px-2"></span>
                   <button class="btn btn-square btn-red" >
                    <div class="flex">
                        <span class="material-icons">
                            do_disturb
                        </span>
                        Cerar
                    </div>
               </button>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you wrote that you imported the module. But check if you imported it into the correct module. As for declarations (pipes, directives, components), unlike providers, they (or modules that export them) must be imported (or declared) in the same module that declares the component in which you use them.

So what I'm saying is: make sure you include the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module that declares `ComentariosSeguimientoComponent`.